# Position of Superscript before automatically sized parenthesis? (Niggli-Notation)

Tags: brackets, superscripts

The superscript (subscript) left of the curly brackets should be further up (down), i.e. same height as the 3 right of the last curly bracket.

Is there an easy way, maybe similiar to \sideset for operators?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

 $ _{\inf}^3{\left\lbrace   \left[ \text{TiO}_{6/2}  \right] ^{2-} \right   \rbrace }^3  $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proposal (not with `\left` and `\right` that you shouldn't be using like that anyhow).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\prebig}[3]{%
  {\mathclose{\vphantom{#1#3}}#2}#1#3%
}

\newcommand{\prebigl}[2]{\prebig\bigl{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\preBigl}[2]{\prebig\Bigl{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\prebiggl}[2]{\prebig\biggl{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\preBiggl}[2]{\prebig\Biggl{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

$\prebigl{_{\infty}^3}\lbrace [ \mathrm{TiO}_{6/2} ]^{2-}\bigr\rbrace^3$

\bigskip

$\bigr\rbrace_\infty^3 \prebigl{_{\infty}^3}\lbrace$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some tweakings, but perhaps better syntax too, we can right align the scripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\prebig}{mme{_^}}{%
  {\mathclose{\vphantom{#1#2}}\leftscripts{#3}{#4}}#1#2%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\leftscripts}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {% no subscript
    \IfValueT{#2}{\sp{#2}}
   }
   {
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {% no superscript
      \sb{#1}
     }
     {% both
      \mammoth_align_scripts:nn { #1 } { #2 }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mammoth_align_scripts:nn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \hfil$\scriptstyle#1$ }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { \hfil$\scriptstyle#2$ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } { \box_wd:N \l_tmpb_box }
   }
  \sb{ \hbox_to_wd:nn { \l_tmpa_dim } { \hbox_unpack:N \l_tmpa_box } }
  \sp{ \hbox_to_wd:nn { \l_tmpa_dim } { \hbox_unpack:N \l_tmpb_box } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\prebigl}{\prebig\bigl}
\newcommand{\preBigl}{\prebig\Bigl}
\newcommand{\prebiggl}{\prebig\biggl}
\newcommand{\preBiggl}{\prebig\Biggl}

\begin{document}

$\prebigl\lbrace_{\infty}^3 [ \mathrm{TiO}_{6/2} ]^{2-}\bigr\rbrace^3$

\bigskip

$\bigr\rbrace_\infty^3 \prebigl\lbrace_{\infty}^3$

\bigskip

$\prebigl[_3$\qquad $\prebigl[^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Just out of curiosity: why shouldn't I be using \left?

Comment: @Mammoth Because it uses too big fences more often than not.